# Return only the numbers before an x-variable equation

Tags: python

I want to save in an array only the numbers before x

```
2x2 - 3 + 4x4 = 7
```

must return

```
[2, -3, 4]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is no `x` in front of `-3`. Also, have ypou tried anything yourself already? Please share your attempts! :)

Comment: Is the input a string? How is -3 "before x"? Lastly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it always going to be operations like a x a, b x b etc? Are you expecting one digit numbers only, or more? What have you tried so far?

Comment: result = re.findall('x[1-9]', equation), but it return ['x2', 'x4'] just the opposite of what i want

Comment: The other before x is 2 :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string with `=` to avoid matching numbers after `=`, strip the spaces, and then use a regex with negative lookbehind to avoid matching digits after an `x`:

```
import re
s = '2x2 - 3 + 4x4 = 7'
list(map(int, re.findall(r'(?<!x)-?\d+', s.split('=', 1)[0].replace(' ', ''))))
```

This returns:

```
[2, -3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return numbers before the `x` only as per your example, but it won't cover the second output of your list (as it does not have any `x`).

```
import re

operation = "2x2 - 3 + 4x4 = 7"
result =  re.findall('(\d)x\d', operation)
print(result)

#>>['2', '4']
```

Note that you were in the correct direction, but as you were not doing any grouping on your pattern, your results were the actual match. [This link on groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) (the parentheses in the pattern) might help.

Comment: clearly mentioned by OP that `-3` should also be included in the output

Comment: It's clearly mentioned as well that it should only return numbers before the "x", so there's a bit of a contradiction in there.

Comment: `[2, -3, 4]` I dont see this as a contradiction. Post as an comment

Comment: I need to include separate numbers as well but with this answer, I can work that. Thank you